# How do I capture text from ListItemButton click in listadapter?

Tags: python-2.7, listview, kivy

**How do I capture the text value from a ListItemButton in a listview and store that text value in an ObjectProperty so that I can use the ListItemButton text value in a different function?**

Error I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adapter'
```

References:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kivy-users/4opq2wsZEKs/XM9f1Psj8JUJ

Screenshot:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHaHO.jpg)

Trying to accomplish something like this in python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import *
from random import randint
import cx_Oracle
import os

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    data = []
    team_list = ListProperty()
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    cols = NumericProperty()
    lv11 = ObjectProperty()
    lv22 = ObjectProperty()
    team1 = ObjectProperty()
    team2 = ObjectProperty()
    list_adapter = lv11.adapter
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fetch_team_list()
        self.list_adapter = self.lv11.adapter
        self.list_adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.respond_list_view_action())

    def respond_list_view_action(self):
        text = self.list_adapter.get_view(ListItemButton.text)
        self.team1 = text

    def args_converter(self, index, data_item):
        return {'text': data_item['TEAM'],
                'size_hint_y': None,
                'height': 25}

    def fetch_team_list(self):
        con = cx_Oracle.connect('SCOTT/******@localhost/j1db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        statement = 'Select TEAM from fbsteampassing group by TEAM'
        exe = cur.execute(statement)
        columns = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
        exe2 = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cur]
        self.team_list = []
        for row in exe2:
            self.team_list.append(row)
        return self.team_list
...
```

Relevant .kv file

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton


TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: 200
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Team Query"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            TextInput:
                id: search_box
                focus: True
                size_hint_y: .1
                multiline: False
                on_text_validate: rootgrid.on_enter()
            Button:
                size_hint_y: .1
                text: "Return"
                on_press: rootgrid.on_enter()
            ScrollView:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '500dp'

                MyGrid:
                    id: rootgrid
                    search_input: search_box
                    lv11: lv1
                    cols: 10
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    spacing: '1dp'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Select All"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                size_hint_y: .1
                text: "Return All Data"
                on_press: rootgrid2.on_enter_2()
            ScrollView:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '500dp'

                MyGrid:
                    id: rootgrid2
                    search_input: search_box
                    cols: 10
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    spacing: '1dp'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Compare Teams"
        StackLayout:
            ScrollView:
                size_hint_x: .5
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '100dp'
                ListView:
                    id: lv1
                    adapter:
                        ListAdapter(data=rootgrid.team_list, cls=ListItemButton, args_converter=rootgrid.args_converter)
            ScrollView:
                lv1: lv1
                size_hint_x: .5
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '100dp'
                ListView:
                    id: lv2
                    adapter:
                        ListAdapter(data=rootgrid.team_list, cls=ListItemButton, args_converter=rootgrid.args_converter)

            Button:
                size_hint: (1, .1)
                text: "Return Team Compare"
                on_press: rootgrid3.on_enter_3()
            ScrollView:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '500dp'
                MyGrid:
                    id: rootgrid3
                    search_input: search_box
                    cols: self.cols
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    spacing: '1dp'
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct answer: you can capture the value from a function bound to `on_selection_change`[link](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.listadapter.html#kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter.on_selection_change) event of ListAdapter. The name string will be stored in `adapter.selection[0].text` property. You can do some more computation from there.

Your code is kind of long, messy, and I have no idea from which line the error comes from. I have an example for you:

test.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0
Screen:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        TeamsGrid:
        ScoreGrid:

<TeamsGrid@GridLayout>:
    rows: 1
    padding: '50dp', '20dp'
    spacing: '10dp'

    TeamsView:
        name: 'left'
    TeamsView:
        name: 'right'

<ScoreGrid>:
    cols: 2

    TeamName:
        id: left_name

    TeamName:
        id: right_name

    TeamScore:
        id: left_score
        bgcolor: 0.1, 0.1, 0.3

    TeamScore:
        id: right_score
        bgcolor: 0.3, 0.1, 0.1

<TeamName@Label>:
    size_hint_y: 0.1
    text: 'score'

<TeamScore@Label>:
    markup: True
    bgcolor: 0, 0, 0

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: self.bgcolor
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import mainthread

beans = {}


class TeamsView(ListView):

    name = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TeamsView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fetch_teams_from_database()
        self.set_adapter()
        self.save_bean()

    def fetch_teams_from_database(self):
        self.teams = [
            {'team': 'Pogoń Szczecin', 'score': '55'},
            {'team': 'Arizona State', 'score': '32'},
            {'team': 'Idaho', 'score': '44'},
            {'team': 'Nebraska', 'score': '48'},
            {'team': 'dummy', 'score': '0'},
            {'team': 'dummy', 'score': '0'},
            {'team': 'dummy', 'score': '0'},
            {'team': 'dummy', 'score': '0'},
            {'team': 'dummy', 'score': '0'}
        ]

    def set_adapter(self):
        self.adapter = ListAdapter(
            data=self.teams,
            args_converter=self.args_converter,
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=True,
            cls=ListItemButton
        )

        self.adapter.bind(
            on_selection_change=self.on_selection_change)

    def args_converter(self, row_index, item):
        return {
            'text': item['team'],
            'size_hint_y': None,
            'height': 50
        }

    def on_selection_change(self, adapter):
        team_score, team_name = self.get_team(adapter)
        team_score = '[size=50]' + team_score + '[/size]'

        beans['score_grid'].ids[self.name + '_name'].text =\
            team_name + ' score:'
        beans['score_grid'].ids[self.name + '_score'].text =\
            team_score

    def get_team(self, adapter):
        try:
            for team in self.teams:
                if team['team'] in adapter.selection[0].text:
                    return team['score'], team['team']
        except IndexError:
            return '', ''

    @mainthread
    def save_bean(self):
        beans[self.name + 'list'] = self.proxy_ref


class ScoreGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScoreGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        beans['score_grid'] = self.proxy_ref


class Test(App):
    pass

Test().run()
```

Comment: This helped tremendously. Great example. In my case I didn't need to use a dictionary like the 'beans' referenced above. These were my main takeaways:

1. If you want to access selection from a listadapter ListItemButton specify the listview in python code as a class instead of in the .kv file
2. Set the listadapter in the listview class and bind the on_selection_change to the adapter
3. Use adapter.selection[0].text to access the string value from the ListItemButton selected from the UI

Thanks for your time with this @przyczajony

Comment: @Krusaderjake The beans dict I presented here is very helpful if your UI has many different elements spread across different trees. This example is simple, but once you have like 10 grids or buttons to reference, using `self.parent.ids.parent.ids. ...` looks dirty and not pythonic. It also helps to clear the kv file. PS: check out kivy's IRC channel for more and faster help regarding the framework.